# SPIVAK calculus chapter 4 question 30.Which Interpretation is correct?

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove that

i)$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^-}f(-x)$

ii)$\lim_{x\to 0}f(|x|) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$

iii)$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x^2) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$

**(These equations, and others like them, are open to several interpretations.They might mean only that the two limits are equal if they both exist; or that if a certain one of the limits exists, the other also exists and is equal to it; or that if either limit exists, then the other exists and is equal to it. Decide for yourself which interpretations are suitable.)**

I think I have been able to prove the required results.I have posted below working for part ii.I would appreciate it if some one could check and see if there are any errors.

But my main problem is which of the interpretations is correct.

ii)$\lim_{x\to 0}f(|x|)=l $

$$\implies \forall  \epsilon  > 0  ,     \exists \delta  > 0 : $$
$$0<|x|<\delta \implies |f(|x|)-l|<\epsilon$$

let y=|x| then

$$\implies \forall  \epsilon  > 0  ,     \exists \delta  > 0 : $$
$$0<y<\delta \implies |f(y)-l|<\epsilon$$

this is equivalent to saying $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=l $

Could someone please check if the proof is correct.

```
                    REGARDING THE INTERPRETATION
                   (Part of the question in Bold)
```

I think that the correct interpretation is that if either limit exists, then the other exists and is equal to it.Am I correct?